# Screen goes completely grey when using Snipping Tool in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, snipping-tool

Screen often goes completely grey when using the Snipping Tool in Windows 10. However, it works sometimes. I checked this [webpage](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/screen-turns-black-or-grey-while-using-snipping/c5df3f63-a3b2-4d35-9501-d6ea081dd619), but still need a solution. This happens using Snipping Tool on any program, not just Internet Explorer. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried the steps on that page? sfc and updating drivers are the first things I'd do... Try Microsoft Snip, does it happen with that also? https://mix.office.com/snip

Answer (score 4):

I too was having this issue and found that Comodo Smart Shopping had installed with Comodo Internet Security.  Uninstalling resolved the screen greying out issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's normal for the screen to go gray when taking a "rectangular" or "free-form" snip.

Also, Snipping Tool will open in the last-used mode, so on any given
startup the screen may be grayed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Its IBM Rapport thats blocking it - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0SHyZPhHyUQ

I turned it off and the snippet tools works immediately.

Comment: link only answer is useless, especially when it will be broken

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in Chrome. I have Opera installed and as a workaround found that the Opera "Snapshot" facility worked OK on the windows that gave me problems in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and for me, it was having Citrix Workspace open at the same time - even if not logged into a session. Closing the Citrix window re-enables both snipping tool and screen share - otherwise both are blocked.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a solution for the root cause, but a method of making the screen normal again.
The white screen prevented me from seeing anything, except when I looked the screen, but after unlocking it continued to be white and the Windows-Key still brought up the menu.
There I opened CMD and (blindly) typed:

`taskkill /IM "Snipping tool.exe" /F`

And pressed Enter.
And the screen was back to normal again.
I killed that task which prevented me from seeing the task manager or using other graphical methods to end it.