# Snipping Tool lightens certain windows (Windows 11)

Tags: windows-11, snipping-tool

The screen-clip utility with Windows 11's Snipping Tool lightens some windows during its capture operation. For instance, in some browser windows the text gets lighter, but in others it seems the same.

Is there a way to disable this or work around it?
Is it documented anywhere?

Executables & versions:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_11.2206.13.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\ScreenSketch.exe

C:\Windows\SystemApps\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\ScreenClippingHost.exe
```

Possibly related: [Screen goes completely grey when using Snipping Tool in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1177281/screen-goes-completely-grey-when-using-snipping-tool-in-windows-10)

Comment: It could be a profile mis-match. Is your workflow calibrated? One common issue is from movies using Rec709 profiles which are then translated wrongly to sRGB. Another is from browsers set to register image profiles incorrectly. Any snipping should be captured with the same profile as you have set for your display & the profile conversion done on the fly.

Comment: (1) Are you using Snip and Sketch? (2) How are you storing the image from the clipboard? (3) Some claim that to fix this you need to change the resolution and then change back. (4) Get a third-party sniping tool.

Comment: Try a trial version of SnagIt.  I have a licensed version of SnagIt and I use both SnagIt and Snipping Tool. I do not see lightened images.

Answer (score 1):

***Turning off [HDR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-hdr-in-windows-11-f5fbf5cb-149d-4a0d-8be1-9ed78c68d3b4) did the trick.***  Under Windows 11 Settings, System, Display, choose your Monitor and switch this off.

[image: HDR off]

Here's a Chrome snip with HDR on and off. Big difference.

---

[image: HDR ON Capture]

---

[image]

---

Microsoft's standard Snipping Tool from their Store is fine.

Thank you commenters for the tips! They put me on the right path, by having me do a snip on each of my two monitors and compare them.

Comment: Glad you found it. I'd never thought of HDR - wouldn't touch that bit of horrible guesswork with a barge-pole. I like to *know* what my graphics are doing. ;))